# RMAN Backup to Disk and to Cloud Parallel

Tags: oracle, rman

I'm currently working on a backup solution for my company.
One part of the solution would be to write the backup to disk and also send it to an oracle cloud archive storage for long term storage.

In the documentation I only found a way to store it in two directories on local disk via:

`CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT '/u01/%U', '/u02/%U';`

Is it possible to define the first backup location to be local disk, the second in the cloud and let rman backup to those two in parallel mode?

I appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance, jan

Comment: How would you specify the cloud backup destination _alone_?

Answer (score 1):

Your local backup uses a disk channel. Cloud backup uses and SBT channel.
The same backup can not be duplexed to mixed kind of channels, see below.

[Duplexing Backup Sets](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/bradv/backing-up-database-advanced.html#GUID-4CFE9BA0-E298-42B8-9FB6-D36751C09D54)

> RMAN can duplex backups to either disk or tape, but cannot duplex
>   backups to tape and disk simultaneously.

Even if you used an SBT channel for the local backup, that would require a media manager library that is different from the cloud SBT media manager library, which you again can not mix.

So the answer is no.

Just create some local disk backups, then backup the backupsets to the cloud.

[About Multiple Copies of RMAN Backups](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/bradv/rman-backup-concepts.html#GUID-763A9C75-90A5-48FD-9CB6-707D030A00F5)

> Back up your files as backup sets or image copies, and then back up
>   the backup sets or image copies with the RMAN BACKUP BACKUPSET or
>   BACKUP COPY OF commands

Answer (score 1):

RMAN: Creating and restoring backups on both disk and tape (Doc ID 1397703.1)

I think one of the reason why backup to disk and tape cannot be simultaneously directly through RMAN, main reason would be the speed for example RMAN is creating a backup piece on disk with speed of 200 MB/s but to copy the same backup piece over network to tape would be 100 MB/s. Because of the difference in speed there is no direct way.

But consider a sample database of 40 TB and you are doing a RMAN compressed backup on disk it takes 40 Hrs to do a compressed backup 5:1 to 8 TB  @58 MB/s. After Disk backup is finished then you start pushing 8 TB compressed backup to Tape using dsmc /* , this will take another 40 Hrs to complete @ 58 MB/s. Total  time you are spending 40 + 40 = 80 Hrs.

Assume RMAN backup to disk is used with parallel 4

Assume RMAN peice size is set to 10 GB,  so assume you have 800 RMAN pieces to backup up to tape

There is a way to speed up backup of this database. When the backup starts RMAN writes the pieces to disk with 4 Disk channels, once it hits the 10 GB limit , it starts creating a new backup piece. So the idea is to monitor the the progress of the RMAN session when it backing up to disk, once the piece of 10G is completed, you can pick up those and start pushing individual pieces to tape ( you can also parallelize the backup to tape  buy running 3-4 dsmc channels, depending on your network bandwidth). Doing so at end of the 40 HRS when your backup to disk is complete, you backup to tape is also 90-95 % complete. In my case using above technique the database backup time reduced from 80 HRS to 40 HRS. ( I can say I backup my database to disk and tape simultaneously).
D2dpt.co.uk